# Преобразовать строку чисел из JTextField

Tags: java

Доброго времени суток помогите пожалуйста!
Мне нужно ввести числа (от 0 до 100) в строку JTextField, разделенную пробелом
Необходимо, чтобы числа были переведены в систему 2,3,4,5, то есть числа от 0 до 60 = 2; От 60 до 75 = 3; От 75 до 90 = 4; От 90 до 100 = 5;
Действия происходят по нажатию кнопки.
И выведите их в JTextArea (пример ввода (42 62 92), пример вывода [2, 3, 5])
Как можно реализовать этот код?
Буду рад любой помощи!

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Answer (score 0):

Так как не видно закономерности - можно обычными if.
Что-то типо такого:

```
int someMethod(int inputValue){
  if(inputValue < 60){
    return 2;
  }
  
  if(inputValue < 75){
    return 3;
  }
}
```

и т.д. В зависимости от задачи можно добавить <= если нужно включительно, в условии этого не сказано насколько вижу.

Answer (score 0):

1. Разбить строку, прочитанную из текстового поля, при помощи `String::split`
2. Использовать `Integer::parseInt` для получения целых чисел из строк
3. Преобразовать числа в диапазонах с помощью отдельной функции
4. Записать результат в список/массив и вывести его в заданный объект JTextArea

```java
String input = myTextField.getText();
int[] result = Arrays.stream(input.split("\\s+")) // Stream<String>
    .mapToInt(Integer::parseInt) // IntStream
    .map(MyClass::convert)
    .toArray();

outputTextArea.setText(Arrays.toString(result));
```

Статическая функция конвертации:

```java
// MyClass
static int convert(int n) {
    if (n >= 0 && n < 60) {
        return 2;
    } else if (n < 75) {
        return 3;
    } else if (n < 90) {
        return 4;
    } else if (n <= 100) {
        return 5;
    } else {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Неверное число " + n);
    }
}
```